# v.category fails to add missing categories to v.type output

Tags: grass-gis, grass-7.2

This is a long story, but I am not certain where exactly the problem is. I started with a polygon (area) that I converted to a line using [`v.type`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.type.html):

```
> v.type input=debug_interpol_area output=debug_interpol_area_border from_type=boundary to_type=line --overwrite
WARNING: Vector map <debug_interpol_area_border> already exists and will be
         overwritten
Building topology for vector map <debug_interpol_area_border@small>...
Registering primitives...
3 primitives registered
89 vertices registered
Building areas...
 100%
0 areas built
0 isles built
Attaching islands...
Attaching centroids...
 100%
Number of nodes: 2
Number of primitives: 3
Number of points: 0
Number of lines: 2
Number of boundaries: 0
Number of centroids: 1
Number of areas: 0
Number of isles: 0
WARNING: Number of centroids exceeds number of areas: 1 > 0
WARNING: Number of centroids outside area: 1
```

`v.type` says that it created three features in the new map, this is confirmed by the info output:

```
 > v.info debug_interpol_area_border
 +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | Name:            debug_interpol_area_border                                |
 | Mapset:          small                                                     |
 | Location:        nc_spm_08_grass7                                          |
 | Database:        /home/desouslu/grassdata                                  |
 | Title:           Output from v.overlay                                     |
 | Map scale:       1:1                                                       |
 | Name of creator: desouslu                                                  |
 | Organization:                                                              |
 | Source date:     Fri Jun 16 16:26:02 2017                                  |
 | Timestamp (first layer): none                                              |
 |----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 | Map format:      native                                                    |
 |----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 |   Type of map: vector (level: 2)                                           |
 |                                                                            |
 |   Number of points:       0               Number of centroids:  1          |
 |   Number of lines:        2               Number of boundaries: 0          |
 |   Number of areas:        0               Number of islands:    0          |
 |                                                                            |
 |   Map is 3D:              No                                               |
 |   Number of dblinks:      1                                                |
 |                                                                            |
 |   Projection: Lambert Conformal Conic                                      |
 |                                                                            |
 |               N:   224659.99999997    S:   223339.99999997                 |
 |               E:            635190    W:            633800                 |
 |                                                                            |
 |   Digitization threshold: 0                                                |
 |   Comment:                                                                 |
 |                                                                            |
 +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But when I try to display this resulting map nothing shows up. After banging my head against it for a while I found out that `v.type` did not create entries in the attribute table for the lines:

```
> v.db.select map=debug_interpol_area_border
cat|a_cat|a_value|b_cat|b_value
1|1|0||
```

`v.category` says pretty much the same thing:

```
> v.category input=debug_interpol_area_border option=report
Layer/table: 1/debug_interpol_area_border
type       count        min        max
point          0          0          0
line           0          0          0
boundary       0          0          0
centroid       1          1          1
area           0          0          0
face           0          0          0
kernel         0          0          0
all            1          1          1
```

This means I can not use this map for any further operations. So I tried to add the missing entries with `v.category`, which fails to even copy the attribute table to the new map:

```
> v.category input=debug_interpol_area_border output=debug_interpol_area_border_cat option=add --overwrite
WARNING: Vector map <debug_interpol_area_border_cat> already exists and
         will be overwritten
WARNING: Table <debug_interpol_area_border_cat> linked to vector map
         <debug_interpol_area_border_cat> does not exist
Processing features...
Copying attribute table(s)...
DBMI-SQLite driver error:
Unable to create table:
create table debug_interpol_area_border_cat ( cat integer, a_cat integer, a_value double precision, b_cat integer, b_value double precision )
there is already an index named debug_interpol_area_border_cat

DBMI-SQLite driver error:
Unable to create table:
create table debug_interpol_area_border_cat ( cat integer, a_cat integer, a_value double precision, b_cat integer, b_value double precision )
there is already an index named debug_interpol_area_border_cat

WARNING: Unable to create table <debug_interpol_area_border_cat>
WARNING: Unable to copy table <debug_interpol_area_border_cat>
WARNING: Unable to copy table <debug_interpol_area_border> for layer 1 from
         <debug_interpol_area_border@small> to
         <debug_interpol_area_border_cat>
WARNING: Failed to copy attribute table to output map
Building topology for vector map <debug_interpol_area_border_cat@small>...
Registering primitives...
3 primitives registered
89 vertices registered
Building areas...
```

If I try to display or query this last output (`debug_interpol_area_border_cat`), the GUI starts spitting exceptions one after the other.

What is going wrong here? Why isn't `v.type` creating the attribute table entries? And is it because of that that `v.category` fails to copy the attribute table?

Comment: After v.type you also need to clean up the left-over centroid - note the warnings "WARNING: Number of centroids exceeds number of areas: 1 > 0" and "WARNING: Number of centroids outside area: 1".

Comment: @markusN Which module should I use to clean this centroid?

Comment: You could use v.clean (https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/v.clean.html#remove-duplicate-area-centroids) or v.extract (https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/v.extract.html)along with type selection to get only the geometry you want.

Comment: @markusN `v.clean` fails, but `v.extract` actually fixes it (using `type=line`). After extracting the lines the layer has no attribute table, but `v.category` (with `option=add`) rebuilds it without issue. Would you like to file an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: @markusN Another thing: there is likely an issue with `v.type` the attribute table in the output is all messed up...

Comment: I'd suggest you bring this up in the GRASS GIS mailing list since more vector experts read there. v.type likely works, it is more about the procedure to be applied (attributes are attached to centroids, not lines). A procedure could eventually be turned into an Addon if it makes sense.